# JSON and jq specifying date ranges

Tags: json, date, jq

Can any please suggest the best way of returning all results which match a certain date.

Input

```
{
  "Status": "Down",
  "StatusID": "72875529",
  "Start": "2017-03-01 04:26:07",
  "End": "2017-03-01 04:36:40",
  "Additional": "Unexpected StatusCode Detected - StatusCode: undefined",
  "Period": "10 Minutes "
}
{
  "Status": "Down",
  "StatusID": "72785390",
  "Start": "2017-02-28 16:24:26",
  "End": "2017-02-28 16:26:01",
  "Period": "1 Minutes "
}
```

I am trying to return the object which for example started in March. I have tried using "match" but it only returns matched string and "contain" only returns boolean values.

I have through about using an if statement however not sure how to specify a partial match as I did not see ~= in the docs as I would need to do something like ~= "2017-03"

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
jq 'if .Start >= "2017-03" then . else empty end'
```

Comment: That can be abbreviated to: select( .Start >= "2017-03")